# Golang error control on parameters when calling a function with reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to call a function using reflection based on it's name.

I first recover the function with

```
f := reflect.ValueOf(s).MethodByName(name)
```

I do error control on the function name by checking if "f" is valid with

```
if !f.IsValid() {
    return errors.New("There is no function with that name")
}
```

And finally I perform the call with

```
f.Call(inputs)
```

My challenge is that inputs depends on the user, and sometimes they can put too many parameters, too little or invalid types.

IE:

```
2019/01/04 16:47:54 http: panic serving [::1]:53662: reflect: Call using string as type int
```

How can I control that the inputs are valid before performing the call?
Maybe there is a way to recover the expected inputs in my method and check them against the provided ones?

Comment: You need to inspect `Method.Type.{NumIn,In}`.

Comment: Could you elaborate or link to any examples or resources?